# How to hide type="file" based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm basically dynamically loading tabs. I want to hide type="file" button on radio button selection for No and N/A .

```html
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.myLst)
{
if (@item.statusID == 1)
{   @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Validate", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AnswerResponse, 2, new { id = "AnswerResponse_1"})Yes</label>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AnswerResponse, 1, new { id = "AnswerResponse_2"})No</label> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AnswerResponse, 3, new { id = "AnswerResponse_3"})N/A</label> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-15">
   <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select1" />
</div>
<button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm">Submit</button>
}
}
else
{
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Validate", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AnswerResponse, 2, new { id = "AnswerResponse_1"})Yes</label>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AnswerResponse, 1, new { id = "AnswerResponse_2"})No</label> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 mt-15">
   <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
      <label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.AnswerResponse, 3, new { id = "AnswerResponse_3" })N/A</label> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 mt-15">
   <input type="file" name="files" multiple="multiple" id="Button_select1" />
</div>
<button id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-pink btn-sm">Submit</button>
}
}
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
           $("input[name=AnswerResponse]").change(function () {

               if ($("#AnswerResponse_1").is(':checked')) {
                   $("#Button_select").show();
              } else {
                   $("#Button_select").hide();
               }
            });
        });
```

My tabs loaded all  at once. My if else conditions not working properly for hiding input type button . In my if condition it only work once.

else condition's block is not working .

Comment: IDs must be unique.   #AnswerResponse_1 is added multiple times in a loop.  `$("#id")` will always only work on the first one.  Change to using a class.

Comment: I changed ids  but still not working in else blocks .

Comment: Could you share your model ?

Comment: the `#Button_select` also seems to created multiples so again id needs to be unique